# Solve $U^TDZ^T = AU^TZ^T$ for $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Let $U$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with rank $n (n < m)$. $D$ is a diagonal matrix of order $m$ and $Z$ is an $T \times m$ matrix mostly rank-deficient.

Can we solve the following equation for $A$:

$$U^TDZ^T = AU^TZ^T$$

Comment: What do you mean be "mostly rank-deficient"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael $Z$ can have $T  < m$ or $T > m$. The cases I deal with are mostly $T < m$, hence $Z^TZ$ is a rank-deficient matrix. That's what I wanted to emphasize there.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation determines $A$ on the range of $U^T Z^T$.  You can solve for $A$ if and only if that has dimension $n$.

Comment: If the column space of $U^TZ^T$ has dimension $n$, how can we solve it?

Comment: If so, $U^T Z^T Z U$ is invertible, and $A = U^T D Z^T Z U (U^T Z^T Z U)^{-1}$.